WSO2 API Manager (wso2am-4.1.0) - Name has exceeded the maximum number of 50 characters Error When Creating APIs
I'm using wso2am-4.1.0 and when creating an API with a name with more than 50 characters, the following error could be observed.

Is it possible to increase the maximum number of characters for the API name as required?
A direction to resolve this issue is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Is it possible to provide the Name you trying to give to this API which has more than 50 characters? It may be a bit unconventional to use a name of that length.
If your goal is to make the API name more descriptive, I would recommend utilizing the description field to provide additional details instead of extending the name.
